# How to avoid rewriting Initializers in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, design-patterns, properties, initialization

With Objective-C I am initializing my classes like that:

```
SomeClass *anInstance = [SomeClass new]

anInstance.importantInt = 4;
anInstance.importantString = @"Vip";
anInstance.importantDelegate = self;

[anInstance initialize];
```

I am doing it like that to avoid rewriting my initializers or to avoid having multiple initializers with duplicated code during ongoing development of a class. I am calling `-(void)initialize` to do the setup of the instance.

This way I can use dot-notation to assign properties and simply add a new line if I need to add properties to the class later on.

To avoid adding `-(void)initialize` to every header I am doing this using an extension of `NSObject` or my own superclass or with protocols.

As I am now starting to work with swift I was asking myself if it still makes sense to do it in this "personal design pattern". Are there concepts in swift that would allow me to easily add properties without rewriting initializers to assign external values?

I already read through the swift guide from Apple an took a deeper look into initialization of classes/structures but I really do not recognize any situation where these swift benefits could help me in my situation.

Comment: It strikes me that (a) this is non-standard; (b) this is fragile; (c) it's unclear what you're doing in `initialize` that you couldn't just as well be doing in `init`; (d) that this `initialize` instance method could easily be confused with the existing class method of the same name. You can refrain from writing initialization methods that let you specify the properties too, if you want, but it seems like you're losing a useful and compact syntax, encumbering yourself with additional burdens, and all for little benefit.

Comment: @Rob I understand. So what about modifying then!? If I write a class and later decide that it conforms to a specific delegation protocol and therefor needs a delegate-property which will be defaulted to nil ... Or optional in swift. So there is absolutely no problem in setting this property after the initialization of the class, right!? That's what I am doing ... This saves amounts of work when extending a class with a property. Especially when this class is used a lot in the project ...

Comment: Yep. if possible, you default it to some reasonable value or to `nil`, depending upon your exact situation. Try to not break existing initializers where possible. But I'd generally extend the initializer to accommodate the new property if it's likely I'd want to specify it (and give that field default value if that makes sense), e.g. https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/658b00944427e8601aff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing any initialization outside of a class's initializers. Luckily, though, it's easy to avoid repeating code. Cocoa has the notion of a "designated initializer", which does all necessary initialization for a class; a class can have other initializers that defer to the designated initializer. In your case, your class would have a designated initializer that looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithInt:(NSInteger)i string:(NSString *)s
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _importantInt = i;
        _importantString = [s copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then it could have a "convenience initializer" that looks like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithInt:4 string:@"Vip"];
}
```

Thus, you can encapsulate initialization entirely within a class, without repeating code.

Swift operates on a similar principle. It allows you to have several initializers. Some can be "designated initializers", and some can be "convenience initializers". A designated initializer generally does all of the initialization for a class. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
init(withInt i: Int, s: String) {
    self.importantInt = i
    self.importantString = s
}
```

The convenience initializer would look something like this:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(withInt: 4, string: "Vip")
}
```

As in Objective-C, initialization is still done entirely within the class, without duplication of code.

Comment: I do know the concept behind designated initializers. I tried to avoid this however in obj-c because of having to rewrite the individual initializer method in both header and source everyone I needed to add a new property to the class. For me it was less work simply adding a property. And setting its value after initialization... What I did in the intialization was setting a default value for example.

Comment: Think of -(id)initWithInt:(int)anInt ... And the a few hours later I added some functions so I need to provide a string so this would mean rewriting the -initWithInt to -initWithInt:andString: .. And it would be necessary to do this in every single place I am using this initializers... So it's easier to call the initializer, set up the properties with external values and then call an -(void)initialize ...

Comment: @SimonKemper: You can still do that in Swift. It's not really a great way of initializing a class (initialization should be self-contained by the class), but you can do it. However, Swift codifies many of the best practices of Cocoa & Objective-C, and additionally, the Swift-Objective-C bridging support is built with these best practices assumed.

Comment: Hmm. I understand. In swift with just having a single code file and no additional header it is less of a problem, btw. But even cocoa & objective-c uses this way of initializing ... If you think of delegate properties from UITableView where you do not set the delegate in the initialization ... That's what I mean. So in swift I would be setting properties as optional, right!?

Comment: So this means there is nothing wrong with setting properties either to a default value or as optionals and perform modification after the initializer!?

Comment: @SimonKemper - No, this simply means you _can_ employ your pattern in Swift, not that you _should._ Swift's initializers and non-optional properties establish a contract for `SomeClass` which make it explicit which properties must be specified and which are optional or have default values. Your pattern completely loses this, and worse, shifts the burden to the calling code. When you add a new property, you _should_ be reviewing the initializer methods to figure out which can survive (i.e. provide default values or become convenience initializers) and which should be retired.

Comment: @Rob your last point is a good one ... Will keep that in mind for my future projects ... Thanks!